# Stop existing instance option when creating windows scheduled task using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am creating a PowerShell script which will create a scheduled task.
Using the Windows GUI, in the settings dialogue, I can set it to "Stop the existing instance" which will close the program if it's already running.
When exporting this task via XML the field is labelled as:

```xml
<Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
</Settings>
```

However, when writing this in PowerShell I only have the options for `IgnoreNew`, `Parallel` and `Queue`.
Is there a way to use the `StopInstace` via PowerShell?

Here is my code:

```bsh
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'cmd.exe' -Argument "/c 'command'"

$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days (365 * 20)) -RepetitionInterval  (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 33)

**$Setting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -MultipleInstances StopInstance**

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Setting $Setting -TaskName "Microsoft Windows > Monitoring Service" -Description "Command Runner"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `StopInstance` enum value currently is not supported by `ScheduledTasks` module.

You can directly set CIM property value instead:

```bsh
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'cmd.exe' -Argument "/c 'ver'"

$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days (365 * 20)) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 33)

$Setting = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet

$Setting.CimInstanceProperties.Item('MultipleInstances').Value = 3   # 3 corresponds to 'Stop the existing instance'

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Setting $Setting -TaskName "Microsoft Windows > Monitoring Service" -Description "Command Runner"
```